# c++ strage solution to compilation error

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, operators, pass-by-reference

Take a look at the following code:

```
struct s
{
    s&  operator+() {return*this;}
};

void foo(s &)   {}

s bar() {}

int main()
{
    foo(bar());     //comp error
    foo(+bar());    //ok
}
```

I think the two lines in main() should be equivalent, because the compiler optimizes away operator+(), right? What sense does it make to accept one but not the other?

Comment: Regardless of what the compiler will or will not optimize away (in your code pretty much every function call does nothing, for example), it still cannot accept incorrect code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `foo(bar())` is trying to bind an rvalue of type `s` (the temporary returned by `bar()`) to a non-`const` lvalue reference to `s` (the argument of `foo()`). This is illegal, hence the compilation error. rvalues can only be bound to rvalue references or to `const` lvalue references.

The expression `+bar()`, on the other hand, returns an lvalue reference (that's the return type of `operator + ()`), which *can* be bound to the lvalue reference parameter of `foo()`.

Beware though: you are returning an lvalue reference to a *temporary* here. While using it inside `foo()` is still safe (the temporary will be destroyed when the full-expression in which it is created is completely evaluated, so after `foo()` returns), you would get **Undefined Behavior** if you stored that reference somewhere and dereferenced it later.

Therefore, instead of regarding this as a "*solution* to a compilation error", you should consider it a way to blindfold the compiler so you are free to sneak into **big** troubles.

Comment: Using the `s&` inside `foo` is okay; the temporary exists until the end of the statement where it was created, which is **after** `foo` returns. Saving it for later use, though, will lead to trouble.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You're right, I overlooked this. Thank you for correcting, I edited my answer.